# AngularJS + ASP .Net Web Api. В экшен не приходят данные

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Не могу понять почему в экшен не приходят данные. Код JS:

```
FSApp.controller('FilesController', function TableController($scope, $http) {    
        $http.post('/values/GetFiles', {dir: "qwe"}).then(function (response) {
            $scope.dirs = response.data.dirs;
            $scope.files = response.data.files;
        });
});
```

код на C#:

```
public JsonResult GetFiles(string dir)
{
    ...
}
```

dir = null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы ожидаете в параметре метода простой тип `string`, а отправляете объект. Опишите тип объекта и фреймворк корректно проинициализирует его полученными в запросе данными:

```
public class GetFilesParam
{
    public string dir {get; set;}
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetFiles([FromBody] GetFilesParam dir)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Тоже самое. В параметрах null

Comment: но метод точно вызывается? брекпоинт срабатывает?

Comment: да, в метод заходит. Брекпоинт срабатывает, но в параметрах null. Только что сделал через JQuery - всё работает, в параметры приходит строка. Но а на AngularJS не работает.

Comment: Нужно было в параметры добавить `[FromBody]`

Comment: @ViktorBylbas, странно, вообще говоря. '[FromBody]' нужно добавлять для простых типов в Post запросах. Для комплексных же, фреймворк сам пытается забирать их из тела запроса (а не из URL) в первую очередь.

Comment: Я не знаю почему именно так, но таким образом данные пришли